# Заменить первый элемент каждой строки матрицы произведением элементов содержащих цифру 3 и не содержащих 5 и больших мин элемента главной диагонали

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const int n = 3, m = 3;
    int a[n][m], pr = 1, min = 10000;
    cout << "Enter matr" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i][i] < min) min = a[i][i]; for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                int t = a[i][j];
                bool valid = false;
                if (t > min) {
                    while (t) {
                        int c = t % 10;
                        if (c == 5) {
                            valid = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (c == 3)
                            valid = true;
                    }
                }
                if (valid)
                    pr *= a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i][0] = pr;
        cout << a[i][0];
    }
}
```

Comment: замена делается простым присваиванием нового значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во внешнем цикле пишете оператор присваивания

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    a[i][0] = 0; // то, что нужно присвоить
```

Но основной вопрос в этом задании сначала посчитать то, чем нужно заменять первый элемент в строках.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!

Answer (score 0):

Вы упускаете  важные детали. Так как логических ошибок много(даже в условии цикла while ), наверное нужно рассказывать что к чему.

1. Вам нужно сначала (в данном случаи, можно сразу при вводе), найти
   минимальный элемент главной диагонали.

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   if (a[i][i] < min)
   min = a[i][i];
   for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)  {
   cin >>  a[i][j];
   }
2. Дальше нужно для каждого элемента выполнить проверку _  если  число больше этого минимального элемента, проверяется дальше:  если есть
   цифра 3, то устанавливаем флаг,  если есть цифра 5, то обнуляем
   флаг(эта цифра не подходит) и заканчиваем проверку.
3. Если, **после проверки**, флаг не нулевой, тогда выполняется
   операция произведения. Пример:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
           int t = a[i][j];
           bool valid = false;
           if (t > min) {
               while (t) {
                   int c = t % 10;
                   if (c == 5) {
                       valid = false;
                       break;
                   }
                   if (c == 3)
                       valid = true;
               }
           }
           if (valid)
               pr *= a[i][j];
       }            
   }
   ```

После  получения результата произведения, в простом цикле выполняется присваивание:

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
a[i][0] = pr;

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за подробное объяснение!  Я постаралась переделать программу, так как Вы сказали, и у меня получается бесконечный ввод массива, не могли бы вы подсказать, где ошибка? Код вставлю в изначальный вопрос.